# Connecting two VMs running in KVM

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, local-area-network, bridge, virtual-network

**Short:** Get two VM's to talk to each other running on same hypervisor.

I have two VMs running under KVM and I am trying to manage them via Cockpit.

The hypervisor, and the vm's are running Ubuntu 20.04.

VM's are configured using br0 (192.168.1.248/24) which points to enp2s0.

They get their own local lan IPs such as:
192.168.1.152
192.168.1.220

These can been seen and pinged on the local lan.
They however cannot ping or see each other.

How can I connect them?

**Detail:**

They don't necessarily have to connect to each other via 192.168.* it can be over virtual network on the KVM host. But they do have to remain accessible on the lan.
I've tried creating virtual network via Cockpit interface

**Tried:**
Creating Virtual Network via the VM interface, but the VMs do not seem to show the virtual interface via ifconfig - just local and enp1so

**Update:**

Not sure if this is related (I am blocked by this in Cockpit interface also, when trying to create virtual networks).

```
sudo systemctl status libvirtd
```

```
    ● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-08-29 13:46:24 PDT; 6h ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
   Main PID: 1068 (libvirtd)
      Tasks: 20 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 32.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             ├─  1068 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
             ├─ 52826 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virtual0.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libv>
             └─182682 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virtual1.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libv>

Aug 29 19:45:25 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:25 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:32 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:33 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:33 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:33 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:39 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:40 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:40 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
Aug 29 19:45:40 dio libvirtd[1068]: internal error: No more available PCI slots
~
~
```

**Discussion:**

Running this on the VMs and Host

```
sudo ebtables-save
```

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

```
sudo nft list ruleset
```

```
table bridge filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

```
ip -d link
```

for br0

```
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:cc:6a:06:f3:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535
    bridge forward_delay 1500 hello_time 200 max_age 2000 ageing_time 30000 stp_state 0 priority 32768 vlan_filtering 0 vlan_protocol 802.1Q bridge_id 8000.4c:cc:6a:6:f3:8b designated_root 8000.4c:cc:6a:6:f3:8b root_port 0 root_path_cost 0 topology_change 0 topology_change_detected 0 hello_timer    0.00 tcn_timer    0.00 topology_change_timer    0.00 gc_timer  280.62 vlan_default_pvid 1 vlan_stats_enabled 0 vlan_stats_per_port 0 group_fwd_mask 0 group_address 01:80:c2:00:00:00 mcast_snooping 1 mcast_router 1 mcast_query_use_ifaddr 0 mcast_querier 0 mcast_hash_elasticity 16 mcast_hash_max 4096 mcast_last_member_count 2 mcast_startup_query_count 2 mcast_last_member_interval 100 mcast_membership_interval 26000 mcast_querier_interval 25500 mcast_query_interval 12500 mcast_query_response_interval 1000 mcast_startup_query_interval 3124 mcast_stats_enabled 0 mcast_igmp_version 2 mcast_mld_version 1 nf_call_iptables 0 nf_call_ip6tables 0 nf_call_arptables 0 addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 64000 gso_max_segs 64
```

**Solution:**
This ended up being Docker running in parralel on the system. Make sure you're not running Docker when installing KVM - as it will block all comms between virtual hosts.

Comment: Sounds like you/libvirt have configured ebtables / nftables to drop certain (not from enp2s0 AND not to enp2s0) L2 forwarding traffics. Or it could be some STP whatsoever configuration.

Comment: Check with `ebtables-save` AND `nft list ruleset` to rule out the former.

Comment: @TomYan I've edited the post with the output info. Ty.

Comment: `ip -d link` on the host also might shine some light (it'll show bridge status, including STP status)

Comment: I've tried both enabling and disabling STP on br0, no changes.